# Can you get the biggest length of a String.Split in a one liner?

Tags: c#, string, refactoring, split

In the below piece of code, is there a way to not need a foreach? All that needs to happen is that if a single of the split parts exceeds a length, i can set it as invalid.

My colleage is sure he used a one line piece of code for this but google left me with no evidence of this.

```
                else if (lineSplit[11].Length > Constant.EstimatedBirthdatesofChildren)
            {
                var estimatedBirthdatesofChildren = lineSplit[11].Split('~');
                foreach (String estimatedBirthdatesofChild in estimatedBirthdatesofChildren)
                {
                    if (estimatedBirthdatesofChild.Length > Constant.EstimatedBirthdatesofChild) valid = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: There will be Linq answers on this. Keep in mind though that these are simply methods that will iterate over the sequence internally, so it could be debated whether they are one-liners or not. The iteration code is still there, but you don't see it.

Comment: would an .Any be faster then a foreach with a break; in it? Also, due to needing to check 97 fields, it would improve readability with fake one liners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lineSplit[11].Split('~').Max(s => s.Length)
```

Oops, you mean you need the first token having more than expected length? your question is not clear, but if yes, you can write

```
valid = lineSplit[11].Split('~').Any(s => s.Length > Constant.EstimatedBirthdatesofChild)
```

Comment: oops, should be: Max(s => s.Length)

Comment: using Max will iterate through the whole collection. Instead, use may use All which will stop and returns at the first value which does not respect the predicate

Answer (score 3):

If you use C# > 3.5 you can do it using one line :

```
string valueToSplit = GetMyValue();
var maxLength = 10;


var valid = valueToSplit.Split('~').All((s) => s.Length <= maxLength);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
estimatedBirthdatesofChildren.Split('~').Select(s=>s.Length).Max()
```

Comment: same as below, using Max will iterate through the whole collection. Instead, use may use All which will stop and returns at the first value which does not respect the predicate